# .htaccess rewrite rule for clean URLs

Tags: .htaccess

I am loking for a .htaccess rewrite rule which redirects from http://domain.com/mydirectory/index.php to http://domain.com/mydirectory/

TIA

Comment: That's not actually a question. Please see [ask] for more information on how to write a good question (and good questions will get good answers!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in your main .htaccess in the root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /mydirectory/index\.php
RewriteRule ^ /mydirectory/ [R=301,L]
```